# TypeORM: How to exclude key property from response?

Tags: sql, node.js, typeorm

**I have the following query:**

```
cors(request, response, async () => {
    const connection = await connect();

    const allAvailable = await connection
        .createQueryBuilder(Topics, 'topics')
        .select('topics.UID')
        .where('topics.tickets = 0')
        .andWhere('topics.chips = 0')
        .andWhere('topics.masteredLevel <= 1')
        .getRawMany();

    response.send(allAvailable);
})
```

**and my response is:**

```
[{"topics_UID":"T001"},{"topics_UID":"T002"}]
```

**But I want this response:**

```
["T001", "T002"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use map it to that property
Add this after querying

```
allAvailable = allAvailable.map(t => t.topics_UID);
```

```
const allAvailable = (await connection
        .createQueryBuilder(Topics, 'topics')
        .select('topics.UID')
        .where('topics.tickets = 0')
        .andWhere('topics.chips = 0')
        .andWhere('topics.masteredLevel <= 1')
        .getRawMany()).map(t => t.topics_UID);
```

Comment: Isn’t there a way to do it inside the query soy the performance remains the same?

Comment: I think no,TypeOrm is an orm it does not come with utility function and that's fair it's an orm not lodash, you can write it as i edited